# how to write a regular expression which matches a pattern if the sentence ends by period '.'

Tags: python, regex

I've a group of strings like following:

```
a phrase containing spaces
A sentence contains spaces as well, but end by period.
```

I'd like to find a regular expression to match the **spaces** (like [ \t\f]) in the 2nd line, which ends by '.'.

I've looked around and found no solution. So I come here for help.

I am using Python, but do not mind knowing the pcre solution even it's not possible for python.

I came out some regex, but it could not exclude the first line.

[my regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ1qA.png)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: All the spaces [ ] and I've edited the question for clearance. Thanks @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Hi @Yong, could you post the code you've been trying so far?

Comment: I was trying `(?<=[a-z])[ ]+(?=[a-z])`, but can not exclude the line without "." ending. @toti08

Comment: Hi @Yong, thanks for your reply. Please provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for guidance) so that we can better help you out!

Comment: hi @toti08 Tim already provided me a solution below. Thanks for your reminding as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a regex pattern which, if applied repeatedly to every line, should be able to match spaces in that line, assuming the line ends with period:

```
\s+(?=.*\.$)
```

### Demo

Here is my attempt at a Python script.  I don't print the space when a match is found, because we can't see it.  Instead, I print something visible:

```
input = 'A sentence contains spaces as well, but end by period.'
spaces = re.findall(r'\s+(?=.*\.$)', input)

for space in spaces:
    print('found a space')

found a space (printed 9 times)
```